# React Laravel Sanctum session doesn't work on cross site access (Laravel new session every request)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, session, cookies

My application is laravel 8.75.0 in the backend serving apis requests for a react frontend.
I am using session to authenticate users, and to store session variables.

On production, react is built, and served statically using apache. Links are:

- http://123.123.123.123/api   -> backend laravel routes
- http://123.123.123.123/dashboard     -> react build folder

The production really doesn't use a domain. It is just an ip inside a corporate network, with no ssl.

On development, I use docker for hosting the laravel backend. React is served on its own. As a result, the links are:

- http://172.18.0.3/api   -> backend laravel routes
- http://localhost:3000    -> react dev server

On successful login, I save session info like this on laravel:

```
$request->session()->put('workplace_id', $workplace_id);
session(['workplace_id' => $workplace_id]);
```

and on subsequent requests, I am getting the value like this:

```
Log::info("check session:".session('workplace_id'));
```

On production, I am able to get the `workplace_id` value. On development, I am not able to get the value because, from what I see, on every request to the api endpoint, a new session file is generated.

This is my code on react:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { wrapper } from 'axios-cookiejar-support';
import { CookieJar } from 'tough-cookie';

const jar = new CookieJar();
window.axios_client = wrapper(axios.create({ jar }));

window.axios_client.defaults.withCredentials = true;
window.axios_client.defaults.credentials = true;

window.axios_client.get(`${API_URL}/api/csrf-cookie`).then(response => {
  console.log("csrf")
})


window.axios_client.interceptors.request.use((c) => {
  const state = store.getState();
  if (c.url && !c.url.includes(`${API_URL}/api`)) {
    c.url = `${API_URL}/api` + c.url;
  }
  if (state.loginReducer && state.loginReducer?.appUser) {
    const { token } = state.loginReducer.appUser;
    c.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    c.withCredentials = true;
    c.credentials = true;
  }
  return c;
});
window.axios_client.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    //const cookie = response.headers["set-cookie"][0];
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      localStorage.removeItem("state");
      window.location.href = window.location.origin;
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

In the code above, I tried to use cookie jar that was recommended in some SO solutions, but it doesn't help.

I got to a point where I can see cookies sent to the server from the browser:

[image]

From the image, you can see there is an alert on the "SameSite" response. It says that `this attempt was blocked because it had the "samesite=lax" though it came from a cross site response, which is not top level navigation`.

You can see that the request cookies samesite are `None`. Also see laravel code below, and you can see that the configuration for samesite is set to none, and it still responds with lax. I don't know why it is happening.

Even though request cookies (XSRF-TOKEN & laravel_session) are always the same, the corresponding response cookies are changing on each response.

To get to this point I had to install self signed ssl certificate with a `.local` domain on the docker apache development server. These are the laravel files:
(relevant parts only)

config/session.php:

```
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE',true),
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => "none",
```

config/cors.php:

```
    'paths' => ['api/*','/login', '/logout', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => ["set-cookie"],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

sanctum.php:

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,localhost:3001,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        //'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],
```

app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php:

```
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
```

Kernel.php:

```
        'api' => [
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this issue. It is explained in this [medium article](https://hershkoy.medium.com/php-session-to-react-without-cors-issue-or-how-to-solve-php-session-is-changing-on-every-request-527a503e9d82).

Copying here the required code changes:

React app.js:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Backend:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", '.dev.local');
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', '.dev.local');
session_start();
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if ($http_origin == "http://dev.local:3000" || $http_origin == "http://localhost:3000"){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Accept');
```

And you need to use a `example.local` domain (set it in your host file).